# Show historical state of customer transaction

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a transactions table that gets populated every time an update is made in source.

`select  updated_date, CRM_CUSTOMER_ID, SVC_TRANSACTION_DATE_C as TRANSACTION_DATE from PRD_SANITISE.PRD_SALESFORCE.SAN_SFDC_TRANSACTION_HEADER`

For each updated_date I need to show latest and earliest transaction as of this date.

I.e if i have a table that looks something like this
[image]

I would like to see a table that looks like this:
Where earliest transaction date is always the earliest available transaction for this customer
And latest_transaction_date is the latest as of the UPDATED_DATE.

[image]

I tried using
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY th.updated_date, tr.CRM_CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY th.updated_date DESC) AS row_num

But no luck

Answer (score 0):

you can use FIRST_VALUE() and LAST_VALUE().

```
select  updated_date, CRM_CUSTOMER_ID, 
FIRST_VALUE(SVC_TRANSACTION_DATE_C) OVER (PARTITION BY CRM_CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY updated_date) as earliest_transaction_date, 
LAST_VALUE(SVC_TRANSACTION_DATE_C) OVER (PARTITION BY CRM_CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY updated_date) as latest_transaction_date 
from PRD_SANITISE.PRD_SALESFORCE.SAN_SFDC_TRANSACTION_HEADER
```